# google.maps.places.Autocomplete not working inside of fancybox

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, google-maps-api-3, fancybox, google-places-api

If you find google.maps.places.Autocomplete not working, but you can see the API calls happening and returning results in the background as you are typing, then check [here](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=20031) for a solution.

Answer (score 11):

Basically you need to find and set the z-index on the div with class pac-container to a higher value. eg: $('.pac-container').css('z-index', 9999);

This container holds the autocomplete results and may not be visible due to being inside of fancybox.

Answer (score 1):

put this code on your pop-up page

```
.pac-container {
   background-color: #FFF;
   z-index: 50;
   position: fixed;
   display: inline-block;
 }

.modal{
 z-index: 20;   
}
```

Hope it works..

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS

```
.popup_container{ 
/* Your popup code */
  z-index: 1060;
}
.pac-container {
  z-index: 1062 !important;
}
```